Floating/sticky CTA design examples on desktop
I can find great examples of sticky CTAs on mobile, but desktop is a little trickier. I'm looking to create something that is not quite a floating action button, not your typical floating 'chat with us' type button, or google material design type button. This is more akin to a floating 'add to cart' button, but our detail pages aren't structured like a typical product details page (because we're not dealing with physical products).
So the ask is, can you think of great persistent CTA patterns on desktop that I can reference as I work through this design challenge?

How are you going to show products added to the cart? Floating CTA is not got for it anyways. U need something that when clicked should show what's in the cart.
I'm not sure why you want to use a CTA for cart functionality!
